# Android: efficient sw design to switch the values of many Views from two sets on user command

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application which contains TextViews and ImageButtons organized in various layouts.

This application receives data from a server and this data is used to fill in TextViews and change ImageButtons icons.

The screen shows the data of a single agent and the system must support multiple agents (let's say two for simplicity, foreground and background).

I have to provide a menu to choose of which agent to display data on the Views (when foreground and background agents are switched, I need to show the latest values I received for the ex-background agent).
Only the data of a single agent can be displayed at any given time on the screen and I cannot use multiple activities.

This problem may have many solutions, but I'm looking for a smart design which can allow me to save some time during development.

A base attempt:

- Do not duplicate Views, only duplicate content (icon status, strings...)
- Every time an update for an agent is received, save it in the data structure of that agent (do not miss "background" agent data)
- Only update the views for the current "foreground" agent
- When the user requests an agent switch (display data of the background agent), update all the views with the content of the new "foreground" agent by calling a function which calls all the functions I use to update the views when a new value is received

A desired attemp:

- Have a single Layout of the GUI which contains all the views for an agent, for each agent
- Hide/Show this maxi layout when agent switch is required

However I do not know exactly how to implement this: is this feasible? Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I decided to design the software.
With two classes I made a clean design which is very easy to use, with a small compromise on the maintenance side, but still highly usable.

The first class (`classA`) stores, for each agent, the value to display for each view of the GUI.
So, if I know the current foreground agent (state variable of the application), I can access a `map<agentId, classA>` and get the value for each view.
Similarly, when a new value is received, I just store it into the `classA` object of the related agent.

The second class (`classB`) is in charge of updating each GUI element, so:

- It stores the reference to each view object of the GUI
- It stores a reference to the `map<agentId, classA>`
- For each GUI element, it has a method to update it which takes a `agentId` parameter to access the right `classA` object from where the right value is retrieved
- It has a single `updateAll` method which calls every update method (used when an agent switch is required)

**Usage example**

When a new data for an agent is received i just do the following (pseudocode):

```
newBloodPressureValue(agentId, value) {
    [map<agentId, classA>].get(agentId).setBloodPressureValue(value)
    if (agentId is foregroundAgent)
        classB.updateBloodPressureField(agentId)
}
```

Design advantages:

- It let me use a single activity
- It let me design the GUI layout statically through the XML file
- It easily supports multiple agents

Design disadvantages:

- If a GUI item must be added, three point must be edited: reference in `classB` members, update method, update method call in `updateAll` method

Comments, critics, suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use multiple activities, you can still use a ViewSwitcher, inside it two instances of your custom layout, and populate the off-screen layout with the new values, then switch Views.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this kind of View. But, if I am not wrong, a ViewSwitcher can only contain Views, not a custom layout, right?

Comment: Any layout will be also a View (its class will descend from android.view.View), so you can add them. There is also ViewFlipper..